# How to disable numa in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7

I append "numa=off" to the end of the lines begin with "linux16 /vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.28.3.el7.x86_64" in /etc/grub2.cfg (like modify /etc/grub.conf in CentOS 6). but after reboot, it takes no effect.
Then I tried to google it but find nothing help.
So does any one knows how to disable it in CentOS 7?

Comment: First things first, does it show up in /proc/cmdline?

Comment: echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/numa_balancing ? that didn't work? Also are you using qemu/kvm? reason for asking is, when it's applied correctly, it gives you very sensible memory management.

Comment: thanks first. numa=0 doesn't show in cat /proc/cmdline, and echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/numa_balancing seems make nothing changed. It's meta server with centos7 fresh installed, jira and confluence fresh depolyed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're trying to disable NUMA.

However, NUMA should be enabled/disabled in your system's BIOS rather than the kernel command line. Is there any reason why this can't be modified in the system BIOS?

Comment: Our DBA ask me to disable it to optimize performance of MySQL Server. I have rebooted just now and can't find numa setting in BIOS (Dell R730) .    __(:3ゝ∠)_

Comment: Find a better DBA (and meanwhile enable interleave)

Comment: Do you mean enable Node Interleaving in R730's BIOS? And I tried "numactl --interleave=all", but returns help message.